# Телеграм боты ошибка на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random
import telebot

token = 'Введите свой токен'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def first_sms(message):
    hai_text = 'Привет друг, я могу искать игры для тебя, тыкни на кнопку'
    keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=False)
    button1 = telebot.types.KeyboardButton('Выбрать жанр')
    keyboard.add(button1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, hai_text,reply_markup=keyboard)

def parsing_games(message,url):
    url_pars = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url_pars.text, 'html.parser')

    data = soup.find_all('div', class_='game_search_par')
    all_game = []
    for games_title in data:
        game = games_title.find('div', class_='title').text
        all_game.append(game)
    game_random_names = random.choice(all_game)    
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, game)



@bot.message_handler(commands=['choose_genre'])#Возможнео изменить
def send_message_game(message):

    questions_game_janr = 'Какой жанр вам интересен?'
    keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=False)
    button1 = telebot.types.KeyboardButton('Хорор')
    button2 = telebot.types.KeyboardButton('Стратегия')
    button3 = telebot.types.KeyboardButton('Экшен')
    keyboard.add(button1,button2,button3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, questions_game_janr, reply_markup=keyboard)
    
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def next_genre(message):
    if message.text.strip() == 'Выбрать жанр':
        send_message_game(message)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сообщение не распознано :(')
    
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def show_game(message):
    if message.text.strip() == 'Хорор':
        url = 'https://vgtimes.ru/games/genres/horror/#gb_top'
        parsing_games(message,url)
    elif message.text.strip() == 'Стратегия':
        url = 'https://vgtimes.ru/games/genres/strategiya/#gb_top'
        parsing_games(message,url)
    elif message.text.strip() == 'Экшен':
        url = 'https://vgtimes.ru/games/genres/ekshen/#gb_top'
        parsing_games(message,url)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сообщение не распознано :((')
    


bot.polling()
```

Comment: Какая ошибка у вас. Можете ли вы отправить ошибку. А то не понятно на что кол жалуется.

Comment: Вы ввели токен своего бота?

Comment: Вопрос закрыт!!!